# Do I need to obtain an Australian transit visa, when flying on to New Zealand?

Tags: visas, transit-visas, australia, iranian-citizens

On an Iranian passport and having already obtained a New Zealand visa, my flight includes a stop in Australia. Do I have to obtain an Australian transit visa?

Answer (score 2):

You need a transit visa as Iran is not in [this](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/transit-771/travellers-eligible-to-transit-without-visa) list of nationalities able to transit without a visa.

([Source](https://www.airnewzealand.co.nz/australia-entry-and-transit-requirements))

Having completed the form on the Australian visa website, you do need a visa:

> [image]

([Source](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-finder/visit))

As shown in the image, this is free, allows you to stay for up to 72 hours and usually processed within 19 days. You can read more details and apply [here](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/transit-771).

Comment: That source doesn't actually show that Iranians are ineligible for transit without visa (although in fact, they are).

Comment: @MJeffryes updated

Comment: No, that still doesn't show it. OP isn't visiting Australia, he's transiting it.

Comment: @MJeffryes it does "All visitors to Australia (except New Zealand passport holders) must obtain a visa, **a transit visa** or ETA before they enter Australia (including travel to Norfolk Islands)."

Comment: If you transit Australia and stay in the international zone of the airport, you don't enter Australia. Citizens of many countries don't need a visa in this case. Unfortunately, Iranians do. https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/transit-771/travellers-eligible-to-transit-without-visa